# Search in firebase database

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry i'm new with firebase.
I wanna search on firebase database to find a specific object.
[image: My Structure on firebase]

how can i find a user that has a specific udid based on my structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go like this.

```
[[[[ref child:@"users"] queryOrderedByChild:@"udid"] 
              queryEqualToValue: yourUDID]                                       
              observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
              withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

       NSLog(@"snapshot: %@", snapshot.value);
}];
```